# Check if URL contains parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string ,

```
var someStr = "http://test.com:4023/somespace/fewusers?LogicalId=lid%3A%2F%2Fkpr.social.1
&kprThemeName=kprBlue&kprCurrentLocale=en-US&kprCurrentLanguage=en-US
&kpr10spaceShell=1&kprspaceVersion=10.34.0&kprStyle=0.0";
```

In a js file I want to check if `someStr` contains `LogicalId=lid%3A%2F%2Fkpr.social.1`.

I am finding it difficult to write a `regx` for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it really need to be a regex? Matching invariable strings with regex seems like overkill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex, just `indexOf`:

```
var exists = someStr.indexOf("LogicalId=lid%3A%2F%2Fkpr.social.1") > -1;
```

However, regex version could be this:

```
var exists = new RegExp("LogicalId=lid%3A%2F%2Fkpr.social.1").test(someStr);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use `indexOf`?

```
someStr.indexOf("LogicalId=lid%3A%2F%2Fkpr.social.1") >= 0
```

Comment: technically that's not a RegEx. :P upvoted anyway :)

Comment: Hehe, true. I'll let you come up with the RegEx. :)

Comment: easy on this one. new RegExp(/LogicalId=lid%3A%2F%2Fkpr\.social\.1/) ^^

Comment: @Robin `RegExp` constructor accepts strings ;)